# How can I contribute to the TeX.sx Blog?

Tags: support, blog, contributing

The title says it (almost) all.

*If and when* I think I have something useful to say on the blog, as a post, rather than a comment, how will I go about it? Is there a moderation process, and how do I provide input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More or less by volunteering here! Martin and I can create accounts, and once you have one then you can create posts. At the moment, we're not using it, but we can set up accounts where the posts have to be checked before they appear.

Comment: OK, thanks. Don't do that (for me) just yet...(:-)