# Posting an article to the blog

Tags: support, blog, contributing

The answer to [How can I contribute to the TeX.sx Blog?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1671/412) outlines the theory of how one can contribute to the blog. How is it done in practice? I wrote a short report on snippets and their use in the typesetting process and I would like to share it with the community. I couldn't find the HOWTO...

I think that a nice way to handle posts from members like myself (in case such a protocol is not there already), is to have some queue where one could send his/her post and after a moderator's inspection it will either be posted, or rejected, or go through some editing iterations phase. In case a method is already defined and established, I guess it should be published; in any case I could find it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contact one of the blog moderators (Joseph Wright and me) so an author account can be created on the blog site for you. You can then start to write the draft of your blog post(s) and submit it for review. The reviewing process you describe is actually already implemented.

There is the [TeX Blog Editor Chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/884/tex-blog-editor-room) which is a good place to post your intention of writing a blog post. Simply notify one or more of the blog moderators using the `@` syntax.

Comment: Is there a preferred way to contact the moderators? I guess this is what I miss then. Thanks.

Comment: You can use the chat for this. See my update.

Comment: Would it be possible to get an author account? I am unable to use chat, unfortunately, it has never worked for me.

Comment: Ooh, I forgot to tell what the topic would be: A visit to local daily papers museum with monotype, linotype and offset machines! `:-)` With the actual people who used to operate them giving a full tour of the place!