# Which prizes for contests?

Tags: discussion, sponsorship, contests

On the occasion of our [Birthday celebration](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/celebrating-the-birthday-of-our-tex-site) beginning tomorrow: which prizes would you suggest for contests or rewards?

Suggestions can range from some smaller prizes up to a few big ones.

Comment: As for the [Contest](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34482/4012), it looks like there'll be two categories with hopefully ranking of best submissions each. How will the shipping etc. of prizes be handled? Could that happen similarly as it did for the swag packages?

Comment: Similarly, however I did not yet get feedback from SE regarding prizes.

Comment: Any news from SE about the prizes? The contest has ended and once the categories of a few of the submissions are clear, we'll have our winners.

Answer (score 8):

As 2 hours are gone by and the birthday is tomorrow, I go ahead and make suggestions. Feel free to edit, it's community wiki.

### Small prizes

- TeX.SX swag
- And more from the SE store, such as T-Shirts

### Medium prizes

- Swag at some higher amount
- The TeXbook or other books
- A one year subscription of a TeX journal, such as TUGboat, Cahiers GUTenberg or DTK, alternatively a one-year group membership if desired (see Barbaras comment below)

### Big prize

- A sponsored two-year membership in the TeX User Group of your choice

Comment: since the PracTeX Journal is only on line, and is open to all, that isn't really much of a prize.  but other user group pubs that are reasonably current -- Cahiers GUTenberg, the GUST Bulletin, Zpravodaj and a couple of others -- are all good fare.  it probably helps if the recipient can read the "local" language, but many articles, even in non-english pubs, are in english or have english summaries, and there are often lots of examples that minimize the need for language competence.  re tug, membership includes tugboat; "subscription only" costs more.  so i'd recommend membership, not sub.

Comment: The only reasonable price would be [a suitcase](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0Uk8H.jpg) filled with [Bank of San Serriffe reward checks](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jrS98.jpg).

Comment: I don't really have any better ideas, but the swag doesn't make too much sense for the top ~60 users, because they're getting it soon anyway?

Comment: I'd like the TeXBook!  Where's the competition?  Can we have a TikZ one so that I have a chance of winning?

Comment: @AndrewStacey Sure, TikZ matches a category in the concept on http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/celebrating-the-birthday-of-our-tex-site